# Import CSV file delimited by double quotes and comma into Hbase using Hive

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I have a CSV file that is delimited by double quotes and a comma comma. It looks a bit like the following:

> "Text from vendor ","Vendor Name, Inc."," blah blah   ","Next string","",
>   1234

I am trying to import it into table in Hbase using Hive.

I am able to create a table from Hive in Hbase using something like the following:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE exampletable1(tax_numb int, tax_name string, tax_addr string, tax_city string, tax_stat string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:tax_name,cf:tax_addr,cf:tax_city,cf:tax_stat")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hiveexampletable1");
```

I was also able to add a table to Hive where I imported the CSV file (although with a problem with the double quotes) using a command like:

> hive> create table example2(tax_numb int, tax_name string, tax_addr
>   string, tax_city string, tax_stat string) row format delimited fields
>   terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

I am however, unable to be able to integrate the "delimited fields" bit into the command where I create an external table in Hbase.

As I'm relatively new to the Hive-Hbase combination I went through a number of tutorials before arriving to a point where I deemed it better to ask the community for help. I ran a number of searches on google, to no avail.

Any help / suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, could you specify a problem once more. Are you having issue with poputating exampletable1 or exampletable2 or else?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to create a table (i.e.: exampletable1) in Hive that stores data in Hbase. Then I'm trying to import a csv into it that uses delimiters like this: "XYZ","YZX".

The problems I'm facing are:

1. Creating the database mapping with the "stored as textfile"bit
2. Overcoming the awkward delimiter of ","

Answer (score 1):

I use org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe as serde to parse this kind of files. For example if I have a csv with 4 fields which are integer, string, integer, string I could use:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable (
    F1 BIGINT, F2 STRING, 
    F2 INT, F4 STRING
)
row format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "^\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\"$")
LOCATION "/somepath";
```

The regexp y always the same, so I generate it with python like this:

```
>>> r = "^" + ",".join(['"([^"]*)"' for i in xrange(0,4)]) + "$"
>>> print str(r).replace('"', '\\"')
^\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\"$
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts at finding a beautiful solution I had to finally resort to going old-school and fall back on awk. The command I used looks kinda like this:

> $ cat inputCSVfile.csv | awk '{print substr ($0, 252, 20) echo "|"
>   substr ($0, 133, 2) echo "|" substr ($0, 297, 13)}'

This gave me what I needed. Then I imported the data into Hive and popped it into Hbase from there. Hope it helps someone in the future.

Comment: Preparing the data are always crucial. TSV would be much simpler to work with under Hive.